# Android: Afollestad Material Dialog action button text color

Tags: android, material-design, android-button

I have been using a library called [material-dialogs by afollestad](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs). I need to change the text color of the positive and negative button action.

```
MaterialDialog(this).show {
            positiveButton("yes") {
                clearData()
                goToLoginPage()
            }
            negativeButton("cancel") { dismiss() }
            message("Some message")
        }
```

The above is the code for showing the material dialog. For the button arguments only the title of the button could be given. My requirement is to change 'yes' to green text color and 'cancel' to red text color. Is it possible to achieve using this library?

Comment: Check out [this link](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs/blob/master/documentation/CORE.md#theming)

Comment: Yes i did. They have provided text color option for title and message, but not for the positive button text and negative button text. So i need some way to achieve that.

Comment: Ok can you show me the code just the dialog you are creating I will check and tell how you can change. Post the dialog creation code in your questions.

Comment: Now i have posted the code in my question.

Comment: Check my answer for solution.

Comment: See my answer I have made changes

Comment: Have your problem solved or not?

Comment: No that does not work with this library

Comment: I have used the latest version of library and its working perfectly as below with Html.fromHtml in my Edit answer.

Comment: The issue is Html.fromHtml("some text ") returns spannable. That cannot be given as argument to positive button text.

Comment: you can give it like this if your using kotlin `val yesText = "<font color='#1B1ED8'>Yes</font>"      positiveButton(text = Html.fromHtml(yesText))` and it shouldn't give you any error.

Comment: what version of library are you using?

Comment: i created an issue in that library. And got the reply that it is not possible to do it in default dialog as it does not follow android material guidelines. If you create a custom view you could set different color for each button

Comment: Good then go for custom views. By the way I have done it using html and I was using kotlin not java.

Comment: You can set color in your theme

<style name="AppTheme.Custom" parent="Theme.AppCompat">

  <item name="md_color_title">@color/your_color</item>
  <item name="md_color_content">@color/your_color</item>
  <item name="md_color_button_text">@color/your/color</item>
    
</style>

Answer (score 12):

Ok here are the three lines you can override in your AppTheme inside styles.xml to give it your own colors.

**To Change Dialog Title Color**

```
<item name="md_color_title">@color/yourTitleColor</item>
```

**To Change Dialog Content Color**

```
<item name="md_color_content">@color/yourContentColor</item>
```

**To Change Dialog Positive and Negative Button Colors**

```
<item name="md_color_button_text">@color/yourPositiveNegativeColor</item>
```

**To Change Dialog Background Color**

```
<item name="md_background_color">@color/yourDialogBgColor</item>
```

**To Change Dialog Divider Color**

```
<item name="md_divider_color">@color/yourDialogDividerColor</item>
```

**EDIT:**

As OP told that he wants to give different colors for Positive and Negative buttons there seems no solution in the library but we can use a work around given below. By using java method Html.from where we can set our own color for each button text.

```
val yesText = "<font color='#1B1ED8'>Yes</font>"
val cancelText = "<font color='#44D81B'>Cancel</font>"

MaterialDialog(this).show {
    positiveButton(text = Html.fromHtml(yesText))
    negativeButton(text = Html.fromHtml(cancelText))
    message(R.string.Some_message)
}
```

Comment: md_color_button_text changes the color for both the button text. Need different button text color for positive and negative.

Comment: **See above Edit in answer**

Answer (score 0):

### always read the docs before posting a question!

check this link for theming and dialog text colors : [material-dialog > docs > Text Color](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs/blob/master/documentation/CORE.md#text-color)

Comment: I did read the docs. They have given option only for title and content of the dialog. Not for the positive and negative button that appear in the bottom of the dialog for user interaction.

Comment: sorry for late reply, but _Text Color docs_ are self explanatory, as `md_color_title` stands for *title text color*, `md_color_title` stands for *content/body text color* and `md_color_button_text` stands for *buttons text color*. i hope they help you out. :)

Comment: read the docs. applied the colour in the styles. still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

try this code,   .positiveColor() and   .negativeColor() and change to gradle version on your project

```
 // Material Dialogs
implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'
```

See full example and download source code, when u takes.

https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs/blob/master/documentation/CORE.md#text-color

Comment: For this he has to downgrade to version where kotlin is not supported and he has to change from Androidx to android and handle issue between manifest mergering.

Comment: No its supported Kotlin, change to this  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'

Answer (score 0):

By default, android:textColorPrimary and android:textColorSecondary attributes from your Activity theme are used for the title and content colors of Material Dialog. colorPrimary is used for the default text color of action buttons. If you wish to override these, there are attributes provided. Use this Custom Style to your Dialog.

```
<style name="AppTheme.Custom" parent="Theme.AppCompat">

  <item name="md_color_title">@color/your_color</item>
  <item name="md_color_content">@color/your_color</item>
  <item name="md_color_button_text">@color/your/color</item>

</style>
```

or Use bellow code to Your AppTheme.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>

    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/InterTextViewStyle</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/InterButtonStyle</item>

    <item name="md_color_button_text">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Hopefully you got the answer. Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution in two steps and it works for me

**Step 1)**
*In style*

```
<style name="AppThemeMD" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="md_color_button_text">@color/YOUR_COLOR_HERE</item>
</style>
```

**Step 2)** *In you activity or fragment*

```
MaterialDialog(this@SplashActivity).show {
                    setTheme(R.style.AppThemeMD)
                    icon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                     title(null, AppConstants.APP_NAME)
                
                        positiveButton(R.string.YOUR_STRING_HERE) {
                     
                    }
                }
```